# Enumeration of a class of languages

Tags: complexity-theory, enumeration

Can you enumerate a class of languages in such a way that the description of every language/ machine enumerated encodes where it was in the enumeration?

Ex:if you are given the description of the bth machine/language enumerated you could quickly check, by some tag or marker in the description of the bth machine / language, that it was indeed the bth machine/language in the enumeration by an enumerator E.

Can you modify any enumerator for a class of languages so that it does this? Or can such an enumerator E be rigged up to do this for any enumerable class of languages?

To give context, my goal is for a verifier to accept, as one part of its input, the machine/language enumerated, and be able to see, quickly, what position that machine/language was in the enumeration by the enumerator E.

Thank you!

Comment: i dont really understand the question. Did you mean to ask if there is a way for a machine to enumerate on a language, and for another machine to verify that it does actually enumerate on it?

Comment: @nirshahar Is there a type of enumerator for every enumerable language that a verifier can quickly verify, when given a word and a number b, that that word is the bth word enumerated.

Comment: Okay. i think i understood now

Comment: When you enumerate, does it have to be in lexicographic order (like the usual enumerator of $\Sigma^*$) ?

Comment: yes--what im asking is that for any enumerable language does there exist an enumerator such that it is quick to verify the spot of any word in the enumeration. Ex: given a word and a number b the verifier would be able to quickly say--yes this word is the bth word enumerated by E.

Comment: @nirshahar Im looking for a way for the verifier to get around actually running the enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

Given any enumeration $E$ of the language, here is a way to describe a language: "the 5th language in the enumeration".

If you use that as the description, then yes, your condition is trivially true.  Given the description of a language ("the 5th language in $E$"), you can quickly find its position in $E$ (5).

Comment: to give you some context, i need to be able to apply the 5th machine / language to a word as well as quickly verify that it is indeed the 5th machine/ language. So, it needs to come out of the enumerator in a form i can use (immediately apply to a word) but also, needs to be self-evident from its description what its position in the enumeration is.

Comment: the code for the verifier is: input: (w,Cb), a word and a description of a machine Cb, check if Cb is the bth machine enumerated by E, run Cb(w). If Cb is the bth language enumerated by E and Cb(w) = 1--> Cb is a proof for w in L. I need the step 'check if Cb is the bth machine enumerated by E' to run quickly. So, i need an enumerator E that tacks on that information of where Cb was in the enumeration to Cb's description so that it is easy to see what place it was in the enumeration-- i need to choose such an enumerator for an enumerable class of languages C.

Comment: basically, I'm asking is there a way to enumerate the machines for an enumerable class of languages in such a way that we add something to their descriptions, a tag or marker, that says: "this is the bth language in the enumeration"."

Comment: But so that they are also still useable--i need to be able to use the machines / languages. So, a combination of a normal enumeration of machines and what you said in your answer. Looking for an enumerator that can accomplish this for any enumerable class of languages.

Comment: Tacking the extra bits on of "this is the bth language/machine in the enumeration" to the description of any machine enumerated i assume we can build an enumerator to accomplish for any enumerable class of languages, but then can a verifier rely on this information?

Comment: If it receives as part one of its input a description of machine Cb, how does it know Cb is the bth language enumerated without running the enumerator? If there is a tag placed on Cb, saying explicitly its the bth language, how can it trust this extra information / tag added to the machine? How can we set things up so that the verifier can QUICKLY be sure Cb is really code for the bth machine without having to run the enumerator E? And the code for Cb, just to repeat myself, has to be executable by the verifier--the verifier as part of its process needs to run Cb on its second input, a word w.

Comment: So the description for Cb can't just be "the bth language in the enumeration". It has to be the code (machine) for the Bth machine + this extra information that it is "the bth language in the enumeration" and this information needs to be quickly verifiable/ trustworthy.

Comment: Or maybe this is fine for my verifier, to just have machine Cb + some bits that say this is the bth machine? Because all i have to show is that such a verifier exists and doesn't fail on some inputs. The verifier doesn't need to know why it's right or confirm / verify itself?

Comment: @DeeDee, sorry, that's too much text for me to read through right now.  If you need 8 comments to explain what your question was trying to ask, then I don't think your question was clear enough.   I encourage you to spend some time figuring out how to concisely and clearly state the problem you are trying to solve, then edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a language $L$ which can be enumerated by a Turing machine, and let $w_1,w_2,\ldots$ be the words of $L$ in order of enumeration. Suppose that to every word $w$ in $L$, you can associate some other word $w'$ of length $\mathrm{poly}(w)$ such that given $w$ and $w'$ you can find in polynomial time where $w$ should appear in in the enumeration, and verify that it indeed does. In particular, given $w'$, you can verify in polynomial time that $w\in L$. Thus, $L\in NP$.

Because $NP$ is a proper subset of the set of recursively enumerable languages, the answer to you question is no.